# Invalid JPEG data (retraining inceptionv3 of tensorflow for poets)!

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I want to retrain inception module, I get the following error (I use the method in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0)

```
root@00aa0e1cd75b:/tf_files# python retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=bottlenecks 
--how_many_training_steps=500 
--model_dir=inception 
--summaries_dir=training_summaries/basic 
--output_graph=retrained_graph.pb 
--output_labels=retrained_labels.txt 
--image_dir=MRII
2017-06-20 15:04:15.616625: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library 
wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your 
machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Looking for images in 'Bold'
Looking for images in 'ASL'
Creating bottleneck at bottlenecks/Bold/1011_221_MR.MR.CCIR-00600_CCIR-
00675_Benzinger_AV45.13.49.20150915.142526.1kyq4ky.dcm.jpeg.txt
2017-06-20 15:04:22.501680: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:332] 
Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in 
GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x50 0x35
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "retrain.py", line 1062, in 
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "retrain.py", line 808, in main
jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain.py", line 440, in cache_bottlenecks
jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain.py", line 392, in get_or_create_bottleneck
create_bottleneck_file(bottleneck_path, image_lists, label_name, index, 
image_dir, category, sess, jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain.py", line 356, in create_bottleneck_file
bottleneck_values = run_bottleneck_on_image(sess, image_data, 
jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain.py", line 275, in run_bottleneck_on_image
{image_data_tensor: image_data})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG 
data, size 147471
[[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, 
dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
Caused by op u'DecodeJpeg', defined at:
File "retrain.py", line 1062, in 
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "retrain.py", line 779, in main
create_inception_graph())
File "retrain.py", line 256, in create_inception_graph
RESIZED_INPUT_TENSOR_NAME]))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 308, in 
import_graph_def
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in init
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 
147471
[[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, 
dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
```

Please let me know how I can handle this error. Thanks!

Comment: If you can find out the file causing the issue then you can go and check it. If the file is corrupt then the script will raise an error. It looks like you had an error saying that you weren't even loading a JPEG file but that might be some other error. Double check your data and see where you get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the image you are using is not a jpeg image.

Error says `Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x50 0x35.` After checking [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) I found that this might be actually .PGM file.

You can use following commands to verify file formats.

```
file /path_to_file/file_name.jpeg
vi -b /path_to_file/file_name.jpeg
```

Just to be sure first try to run it with one or two images.